# PHP PDO MySQL duplicate output

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I'm using PHP PDO to connect to a MySQL database and returning a result set, but I seem to be getting duplicate output although there are only 2 records in my database.

MYSQL:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM nouns;
+-----+---------------+---------+
| PID | german        | english |
+-----+---------------+---------+
|   1 | die Männer    | men     |
|   2 | die Frauen    | women   |
+-----+---------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

PHP Snippet 1:

```
$database = new MySQLConnect();
$database->query("SELECT german, english FROM nouns;");
while ($row = $database->row()->fetch()) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
    $data .= $value;
}
```

PHP Snippet 2:

```
interface IMySQLSettings
{
    const HOSTNAME = "hostname";
    const DATABASE = "database";
    const USERNAME = "username";
    const PASSWORD = "password";

    function __construct();
    function query($query);
    function row();
}

class MySQLConnect implements IMySQLSettings
{
    private $hostname = IMySQLSettings::HOSTNAME;
    private $database = IMySQLSettings::DATABASE;
    private $username = IMySQLSettings::USERNAME;
    private $password = IMySQLSettings::PASSWORD;

    private $connect;
    private $query;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->hostname;dbname=$this->database", $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    function query($query)
    {
        try {
            $this->query = $this->connect->prepare("$query");
            $this->query->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function row()
    {
        return $this->query;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
die Männerdie Männermenmendie Frauendie Frauenwomenwomen
```

Comment: Where is the code that generates your output?

Comment: posted code has syntax error. also no debugging efforts. and obviously: `$database->row()->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`

Comment: Extremely orthodox class structure. And the code uselessness at the same degree... What's the point in having distinct row() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your fetch you must provide PDO::FETCH_NUM or PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, as PDO::FETCH_BOTH is default value.

Maybe when you construct PDO object add this line

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

More info [PDO fetch_style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Here is what you get from php.net manual:

```
PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
Array
(
    [NAME] => apple
    [COLOUR] => red
)

PDO::FETCH_BOTH
Array
(
    [NAME] => banana
    [0] => banana
    [COLOUR] => yellow
    [1] => yellow
)
```

Answer (score 0):

a refactored version with all the useless code taken out, yet required functions added.

```
class MySQLConnect
{
    private $connect;

    function __construct()
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".IMySQLSettings::HOSTNAME.";dbname=".IMySQLSettings::DATABASE;
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
         );
        $this->connect = new PDO($dsn, IMySQLSettings::USERNAME,IMySQLSettings::PASSWORD, $opt);
    }

    function query($query, $params = array())
    {
        $stmt = $this->connect->prepare($query);
        return $stmt->execute($params);
    }
}

$db = new MySQLConnect();
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT german, english FROM nouns");
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $value) {
    $data .= $value;
}
```

Though I kept that IMySQLSettings thing, it is totally **useless** as interface.
What if I need another database to connect? Redefine MySQLConnect to implement another interface?

Instead of fancy inteerface it have to be a mere array, passed into MySQLConnect's constructor.